# Delay jQuery effects whilst page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have this bit of code:

```
$("#comingsoon, #1, #2, #3").hide().each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i * 500).slideDown(1500);
});
```

Which basically fades in a series of objects on my page, problem is that the animation lags horribly when the flash banner at the top of the page is loading. I would like to delay the entire jQuery animation for about 2-3 seconds.

Anyone got any ideas.

Comment: Maybe also answer to the question [Jquery taking effect after the page is loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16843372/775066) might help a little.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already using `delay`, you could just add a fixed interval to your current variable interval:

```
$("#comingsoon, #1, #2, #3").hide().each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(2500 + i*500).slideDown(1500);
});
```

(That 2500 adds a 2.5 second delay before the slideDowns start.)

If you want to delay *hiding* as well, put your whole thing in a delayed function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#comingsoon, #1, #2, #3").hide().each(function(i) {
      $(this).delay(i*500).slideDown(1500);
    });
}, 2500);
```

That won't even hide things until 2.5 seconds after that code is run.

[See also John Gietzen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874411/delay-jquery-effects-whilst-page-is-loading/3874463#3874463): If you want to wait until all page content is loaded (which can be a long time, but perhaps exactly what you want here), use the `window` `load` event instead of `jQuery.ready`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are using `$(document).ready()` to fire your code.

If you want to wait until the DOM *and all of the page content* has loaded, you can use `$(document).bind("onload", ...);`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).load(function () {
     $("#comingsoon, #1, #2, #3").hide().each(function(i) {
     $(this).delay(i*500).slideDown(1500);
     });
});
```

That executes when the window [loads](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) fully and not when the DOM is [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the setTimeout() function.

```
setTimeout(   function() {

    $("#comingsoon, #1, #2, #3").hide().each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(i*500).slideDown(1500);
    });

}, 3000);
```

Comment: Just don't forget to add quotes around the first argument (function).